# PHP mysql-7.2 cannot install on Ubuntu

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu

Im trying to switch my server to PHP 7.2.
Ive got it working on Apache2, and its running fine.

The only issue is the MYSQL extension is not working.

I've commented these lines in php.ini

```
extension=mysqli
extension=pdo_mysql
```

But it appears that I dont even have the mysqli extension in the first place.

I try installing it like so

```
 sudo apt-get install php7.2-mysql
```

But I just get this error

```
E: Unable to locate package php7.2-mysql
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.2-mysql'
```

Ive tried running

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Along with following the instructions here and installing some python packages
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1184367/how-to-install-php7-2-in-ubuntu-19-10

But nothing seems to work.
How do I get PHP7.2 working with MYSQL???

Comment: Why not ask your Ubuntu-related question on [ubuntu.se] Stack Exchange?  After all, this is exactly why the SE community was born.

Answer (score 0):

[php7.2-mysql](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=php7.2-mysql) exists in ubuntu-18.04/bionic only.

[php-mysql](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=php-mysql&searchon=names) maps to different versions, so maybe if your using later ubuntu version a >7.2 version will be retruned.